# Google Web fonts not correctly rendering in Safari

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

I am using google-webfonts in my website,

```
body {
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
}
```

Link the font in layout page using

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This is perfectly work in Chrome and firefox. But in Safari, font is mor bold, i try to fix the font weight, but not worked. how can i solve this problem

Comment: Different browser and OS combinations render fonts differently, slight variations are expected.

Comment: what safari version have you got?

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33959265/1624933 see my comment too

Answer (score 7):

Google Fonts provides three methods of import: `< link >`, `@import` or JavaScript). Regardless your choice, the request's response is always the same, a list of font faces.

The "url" descriptor of each font-face provides the paths where the binary should be picked. First, it will try the installed fonts in the OS, if fails, fetch in Google Fonts.

Somehow Safari don't get the right font for the desired "font-weight" if the font is in the OS. In my case, I set "font-weight" to 100, so it should use "Roboto-Thin", but it gets "Roboto-Light" instead.

**The easiest solution is uninstall the font and let Google provide it** (I did this to Roboto). If that is not good for you, there is another option: do not use the import methods described above and define the font faces yourself.

For these, paste the URL that Google provided in the browser, copy the CSS code provided and paste in your own CSS file.

e.g.:

```
# Firefox.
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'),
       local('Roboto-Thin'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxHYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/vzIUHo9z-oJ4WgkpPOtg13YhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'),
       local('Roboto-Light'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfbO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CrYjSnGjrRCn0pd9VQsnFOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff');
}


# Chrome.
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'),
       local('Roboto-Thin'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxHYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'),
       local('Roboto-Light'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}


# Safari.
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'),
       local('Roboto-Thin'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Jzo62I39jc0gQRrbndN6nXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'),
       local('Roboto-Light'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfSZ2oysoEQEeKwjgmXLRnTc.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/QHD8zigcbDB8aPfIoaupKOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.ttf) format('truetype');
}


#IE.
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot);
}


# Final:
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'),
       local('Roboto-Thin'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxHYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/vzIUHo9z-oJ4WgkpPOtg13YhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff) format('woff'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Jzo62I39jc0gQRrbndN6nXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.ttf) format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'),
       local('Roboto-Light'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfbO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfSZ2oysoEQEeKwjgmXLRnTc.ttf) format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'),
       local('Roboto-Regular'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CrYjSnGjrRCn0pd9VQsnFOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/QHD8zigcbDB8aPfIoaupKOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot);
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: This does not helped me too.  Safari 9

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Safari has yet to support woff2. It does support woff. So you have to find the woff version urls and change the format to woff.

1. Visit: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
2. Click the "Try it out in TypeCast" link at lower-right.
3. Click "Download HTML/CSS" at the left panel.
4. Open the downloaded index.html.
5. Copy the value of `link_element.href +=`
6. Type "http:" and paste above in your browser.

For example:
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,500italic,500,700italic,700,900italic,900

These are the woff versions.

Comment: This does not worked for me with Roboto Slab, Safari 9