# Google font not loading on ios mobile browsers

Tags: css, ios, fonts

Fonts are loading fine in Firefox, Opera, Safari, Edge  - all OSX plus on iOS Safari, Firefox iPad.
Fonts are **NOT** loaded on Safari and FireFox iOS iphone 7.

Here is my CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Oswald-Regular.eot');
    src: url('/public/fonts/Oswald-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/public/fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/public/fonts/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have no idea what the problem could be.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Font not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061808/google-font-not-working-on-safari)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried everything mentioned. The font shows fine on Safari OSX. The iOS webkit browsers are not showing the font. -Thanks