# Roboto font not working in Safari or Mobile browsers after deployment on Netlify

Tags: html, css, reactjs, netlify, roboto

Pulling my hair out here.

I'm new to React, I have my font family in my css like this. Everything is fine on localhost but when I deploy, the Roboto font doesnt work on safari or mobile browsers...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important;
  border: none;
}
```

also i'm using styled components, i'm not too sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Please post the link to your webapp.

Comment: savetheelephants.netlify.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above solution did not work:

Try downloading the font font instead of importing the font this might work ( procedure mentioned below in 3rd point ).
Some other things you should check is in this SO question: [A related question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061808/google-font-not-working-on-safari/24062128)

1. You should also include font-weight and font-style properties(worked for some)

- It should look something like this:

  ```
  font-family: 'Roboto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  font-style:italic;
  ```

2. If you are importing the font font in the css file like this:

   ```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap')
   ```

   then change it and import it in the html file in the `<head>` tag or just
   follow the code:

   ```
   <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" 
     rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   ```
3. If all of the above fails then download the font from google fonts and do this in your
   root css file

   ```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Font_name';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Font_name'), url('Font_name.woff') 
    format('woff');
    }

   *{
     font-family: Font_name
    }
   ```

- After downloading the font from google fonts do not forget to move the .woff
  files to project directory else its
  not going to work
- I tested it out on app.lambdatest.com and it worked well and the screen shot
  of the result is here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: You dont have to have do anything, just your css rules is wrong in the production build

**Your Code:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important;
  border: none;
}
```

You told that this is your code but in the deployed version it says `font-family: "Roboto"` just fix this and it might work or follow the bellow instructions

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept when you can the ones that solved your problem. Glad to help!