# How do I get safari to show my Google Fonts correctly?

Tags: html, css, safari

For some reason I can't get Google Fonts to work correctly on Safari. Both on a Mac and on mobile. Any suggestion to what I can improve to make it work on Safari too?

I have tried both

```
<style>
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap');
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;500;700&display=swap');
</style>
```

and

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Even embedding them locally as Woff2 fonts.

The CSS to show the font is

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #6b6a6a;
    font-family: oswald !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background:#202020;
    background-size: contain;
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.text_widget {
    font-family: lato !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Is it working on other browser ? Please provide live demo to help

Comment: I don't a public page yet, and yes it's working in all other browsers. Could it be some server settings maybe? I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS property -webkit-text-size-adjust. Here's a sample of how to apply this to your body, just for the iPhone:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
  body{
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, not at the office right now so can't test until later. But doesn't this only affect the size? The problem is that it's using times new roman instead of the google font.

Comment: hmm can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959265/14618967